# How to navigate from one dropdown menu to next dropdown menu in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, drop-down-menu, popup

In whatsapp, when we go to any particular user then at right corner there is more option (three dots menu). Then after clicking that menu, one list will come and again at last row there is navigate arrow, then after clicking on that row again new menu will come.
here is the images,

[image: img1]

after clicking on more option, following view will appear

[image: img2]

I want to implement this feature in my iOS Project. Anyone have any idea how to implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it with multiple ways!

First Way : Take two table view for the menu. Initially keep one tableview hidden. Then on more's click of first tableview, show second tableview and hide firt one.

Second Way : Take only one tableview and reload different data. I mean on click of main change your datasource for tableview and reload it.

Answer (score 0):

`DropDown` menu's are considered bad practice in iOS. Use one `UIAlertController` to show first options, than on selecting the `More` show another `UIAlertController`.